# R read flat(no formatted file) and split

Tags: xml, r

I have huge test.xml file (yes it's in XML format), I just need it to split to probably 5 parts by line number or node  for easy processing into sql, and trying to do this with R,
so first step would be probably to load it into df, how I can do this, I don't care about any columns, etc, this is pure xml file.
looks like read.table requires some columns, etc....
below are just my ideas which didn't work..

```
d = read.table ("C:/Users/tangosg/Downloads/test.xml")
d <- split(my_data_frame,rep(1:400,each=1000))
```

Comment: Data frames require some semblance of a column structure, so I don't think `read.table()` is going to be the right tool for the job here.

Comment: Try something like `d <- scan("C:/.../text.xml", what = character(), sep = ...)`, with some actual value for `sep`. Take a look at `?scan`, particularly the `sep` argument.

Comment: The file or a reproducible example of it would be useful, your `split` function doesn't look like it will work (for starters, you're not applying it on the data you just read).

Comment: I added an XML tag to help people interested in XML and R find your question. You really should provide a small example XML file and also show what the output should be after the XML file has been transformed.